# Can't find Note API Name

Tags: notes

I enabled Notes and added the related list to Opportunities.  I created a note on my Opportunity and see the note on the Opportunity.  I cannot find where this actually gets stored at.  I ran a subquery on Opportunity for Tasks, Notes, Attachments.  None of these contain the Note that I just created.  Where can I find this Note?

Comment: run `for(Schema.ChildRelationship cr : Opportunity.SObjectType.getDescribe().getChildRelationships()){
    System.debug(cr.getChildSObject() + '.' + cr.getField() + ' reversed is: ' + cr.getRelationshipName());
}`   in dev console and check all the child object name and try to find your

Comment: @sfdceweb Actually Right as you put that in, I found it.  Seems like it's 'AttachedContentNotes' is the related list.

Comment: dphil... Then you can give answer to your own
 question.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find it using the Schema in Eclipse.

AttachedContentNotes is the related list item.